# cant find {gameobject.findgameobjectwithtag} in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started yesterday game dev with Unity. I was watching some tutorials on YouTube and I can not find {gameobject.findgameobjectwithtag} and now I know the basics of coding in unity but I don't know how to solve this problem

I rewrote everything and still have the problem

Comment: Why did you tag with C++ if you're asking about C#?

Answer (score 0):

Unity is case sensitive, so see if you are making any spelling or wrongly typing the case. Also, to find a gameobject with tag, you need to tag the gameobect in the inspector. Share the code and a screenshot of how you have assigned the tag

Here are some basics on [finding a gameobject](https://vionixstudio.com/2022/03/31/how-to-find-a-gameobject-in-unity/) in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 functions one is [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) and the other one is [GameObject.FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)

The difference between the 2 is that the first one it will return an array of all `GameObjects` that have the tag that you are searching for. Also it will return an empty array if no GameObject was found.

The second method it will simply return the first active GameObject inside your hierarchy with the given tag. It will also return null if no GameObject was found.

**Note:** On both links that I've provide are directly from Unity's official documentation, so please take a look on both of them.